# extract numerical values from DataFrame string object

Tags: regex, pandas, extract, dataframe, numerical

I have a DataFrame object of dtype string. A typical row looks like below:

```
'\n\n              Dividend Indicated Gross Yield\n          \n\n              1.50%\n          \n'
```

I am trying to extract only the numerical data from the above string. for example, my desired output should be `1.50`.

The other thing to keep in mind is that each row will have different length of numericals and some may include a negative sign too.

I have tried some recommendations involving `.rstrip()`, `regex`, `convert_objects` but they do not work as intended. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you post some of the `regex` you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to do this:

```
df.col.str.extract('(\-?\d+\.\d+)').astype(np.float64)
```

Comment: i tried the above solution but it throws a error message: "ValueError: This pattern contains no groups to capture."

Comment: I made a mistake with the regex, it needs a set of parentheses to tell it which group to extract, it should work now.